# Firebase analytics refresh rate

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I wanted to ask how often to firebase anaylitics refresh?

The current downloads seem to be stuck at a certain value even though I'm 101% sure that there are more. When do firebase analytics refresh?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Firebase Analytics documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/#implementation_path):

> You can view analytics data in the Firebase console **within hours**.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you set the date range to include Today.  Ranges like "Last 30 Days" and "Last 7 Days" do not include Today's date.